# how to use the function anova1 with strings

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array containing the gender e.g.

```
GENDER = {'Male';'Female';'Male';'Male';'Male';'Female';'Female';'Female';'Male';'Male'};
```

and another array containing the respective groups e.g.

```
GROUPS = [1; 2; 1; 1; 3; 3; 1; 2; 2; 3];
```

I would like to find whether there are significant differences between the groups in the number of male and number of female. I would like to use the functions anova1 + multcompare as in the example provided in the help.

How can I treat this case?

```
anova1(GENDER,GROUPS,'off')
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in anova1 (line 46)
if (nargin>0 && strcmp(x,'kruskalwallis'))
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: A small recommendation: Before using statistical functions, understand the statistics.

Comment: thanks but I think that I understood anova...maybe I was not clear in my question...please see the comment to your answer..

Comment: Ok, now I understand better. Made another attempt at answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't defined the *numerical quantity* the ANOVA should operate on. From your description, there are different possible interpretations as to what that quantity should be. One possibility: The difference between the absolute number of males and the absolute number of females. For this you could encode a "male" observation by +1 and a "female" observation by -1:

```
GENDER = [ 1;  -1;   1;   1;   1;  -1;  -1;  -1;   1;   1];
```

The GROUPS variable could stay as you specified it, but since the entries are actually not treated as numerical values but as group labels, maybe its better to write it as such:

```
GROUPS = {'1'; '2'; '1'; '1'; '3'; '3'; '1'; '2'; '2'; '3'};
```

Then your call to `anova1` works

```
anova1(GENDER, GROUPS, 'off')
```

and returns a p-value of 0.609, i.e. clearly not significant.

You do not need `multcompare` since you only examine the main effect in a one-way ANOVA, resulting in a single p-value.

Another problem is that the ANOVA, as stated in the help for the function, assumes normally distributed data. The GENDER variable as defined above is clearly not normally distributed but rather Bernoulli-distributed. I know it is common practice in some fields to analyse these kinds of data using an ANOVA, but it is not statistically correct.

Comment: my GROUP array contains the groups to which the subjects in gender belong. e.g 1st subject (male) belongs to group 1. The 2nd subject (female) belongs to group 2. I want to see whether there are differences between groups. I have 3 groups so I think I need to use multcompare.  And for this reason I should use anova1 with GENDER as first argument and GROUPS as second. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. The values I gave were just an example. I've a dataset of more than 1000 subjects. Assuming that I've a significant p value (<0.05) then I need multcompare to understand which group is different from which...is that correct? Moreover I understand your point regarding the normal distribution and I agree! can you suggest an analysis that is adequate for a bernulli distribution? Moreover my dataset is not balanced (I have a different number of observations for each group).

Comment: Well, the point of an ANOVA is not to compare pairs of groups separately, but to say whether groups differ in general ("main effect"). Of course you could also do three pairwise comparisons, resulting in three p-values, and then you would have to do a correction by a factor three, i.e. compare the p-values with a threshold 0.05 / 3 = 0.01666.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple ready-to-use Bernoulli-adapted version of an ANOVA. You could do the following: Do not use the p-value returned by `anova1`, but the F-value; you can extract it from the second output of `anova1`, "anovatab". Now randomly permute your group labels (have a look at `randperm`) and compute the F-value again. Do this about 200–1000 times. Compare your actual F-value with those values. If less than 5% are larger, your result is significant. This kind of procedure is called "permutation test". See P. Good, *Permutation, Parametric and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses*.

Comment: The error you make using the ANOVA is less severe the more data you have. With 1000 subjects, it might be ok.